# How does Java evaluate this statement?

Tags: java, expression, evaluation, operator-precedence

I have this expression in the if else statement

```
if (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0 || row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 1) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

which behaves as intended, returning  0 when the row and column are either both even or both odd. What perplexes me is how Java didn't read it as

```
(row % 2 == 0 && (col % 2 == 0 || row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 1))
```

How exactly does Java evaluate a statement without parenthesis?

Comment: By using the precedence rules set out in the JLS? Was this a trick question of some sort? :-)

Comment: always use parentheses when in doubt (and even when not). Makes it easier to read for everyone and eliminates room for errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How exactly does Java read a statement without parenthesis?

By applying the *operator precedence* rules.  The Java language specification says that `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`, and that means that:

```
    row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0 || row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
    (row % 2 == 0 && col % 2 == 0) || (row % 2 == 1 && col % 2 == 1)
```

And in fact, `==` has a higher precedence than `&&`, so that is equivalent to:

```
    ((row % 2 == 0) && (col % 2 == 0)) || ((row % 2 == 1) && (col % 2 == 1))
```

[This page from the Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) provides more information on operator precedence and how it affects expression evaluation.

---

For what it is worth, there is a natural parallel between operator precedence in a programming language and the meaning of *simple arithmetical expressions* ... as you were taught in primary school.  For example, you were taught that `1 + 2 x 3` means the same thing as `1 + (2 x 3)`; i.e. the answer is `7` and not `9`.  In technical terms, the `x` (multiplication) operator has higher precedence than the `+` (addition) operator.

The idea is the same in a typical programming language, except that there is a larger range of operators to deal with ... and the rules are (generally speaking) more precisely specified<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - For instance, since the evaluation of primaries and operators can in some cases have *side effects*, it can be important to know the precise order in which the sub expressions get evaluated.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

That is because of the precedence order. `&&` has precedence over `||`.

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).